# Binary image is not displayed

Tags: java, image, image-processing, edge-detection

I'm doing an image detection which I have to process on each red, green, and blue element to get the edge map (binary image in black and white form) and combine them become one to show the output. After I extract the element of each red, green, and blue and set thresholding value to get the binary image, it doesn't show the binary image. Instead it shows me the grayscale image. Would anyone please be kind enough to help me? Here is my code so far.

```
Buffered Image buff_red;
int[] process_red;
int width = 256; 
int height = 256;

private void processActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 
width = inputimage.getWidth(null);
height = inputimage.getHeight(null);

buff_red = new BufferedImage(width,height,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
Graphics r = buff_red.getGraphics();
r.drawImage(inputimage, 0, 0, null);
r.dispose();

//get the red element
process_red = new int[width * height];
counter = 0;
 for(int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
     for(int j = 0; j < 256; j++) {
         int clr = buff_red.getRGB(j, i);
         int red = (clr & 0x00ff0000) >> 16;
         red = (0xFF<<24)|(red<<16)|(red<<8)|red;
         process_red[counter] = red;
         counter++;
     }
}

//set threshold value for red element
int threshold = 100;
for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
     int bin = (buff_red.getRGB(x, y) & 0x000000ff);
     if (bin < threshold)
               bin = 0;
     else
               bin = 255;
     buff_red.setRGB(x,y, 0xff000000 | bin << 16 | bin << 8 | bin);
     }
}
```

#### Update:

Initialization of `buff_red` was done before the "get red element" (first loop), which is:

```
buff_red = new BufferedImage(width,height,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
Graphics r = buff_red.getGraphics();
r.drawImage(inputimage, 0, 0, null);
```

Should I buffer the image from `process_red` and use it for thresholding method so that I can get the edge map?

Comment: Can you please show me your code i was also working on the same process of 

converting RGB image to Gray image then gray image to Binary image.

Comment: How far you have worked on it? You can show us what you've done and we can help you with your problem.

Answer (score 1):

One thing that looks suspicious from your code is that your "get red element step" (first loop) writes to `process_red`, but your thresholding step (second loop) reads from `buf_red`, which doesn't seem to be initialized anywhere.  Is this a typo, or a bug in your code?

You mention edge detection, but I can't see anything that looks like edge detection in the code that you posted.  All you seem to be doing is extracting the red (green, blue) channels, thresholding them, and then combining them.

It would help if you were more analytical in your approach to the problem.  What is the earliest point where the problem manifests yourself?  Are you extracting the channels from the image correctly?  Do your edge detection images look right?  Is your thresholding result giving you what you expect?  You can answer all of these questions by yourself -- write/show debug images.

Finally, ideally you shouldn't have to manually code such low-level mundane tasks (fetch pixel, mask by `0xff`, etc) by coding them yourself, at least in Java.  It's fun the first time through, but after that it's just another source for bugs and unexpected features.  I don't currently use Java, but I'm certain that it has an image processing API that can handle such tasks for you.

Comment: hi, thx for ur response. actually i repeat the same process i've done before in which an original image is converted to a grayscale image and i threshold it. from that process i got the edge map so i thought by doing the same process to each RGB components will give edge map as well. from what u explained i got that after first loop i have to threshold it from process_red, am i right? pls correct me if im wrong. thx again.

Comment: I misunderstood what you meant by "edge map".  It hints at *edge detection*, which is generally a bit more involved than just greyscale conversion and thresholding.

Comment: yes, after conversion to grayscale, i do the thresholding process in which if frequency of the color is less than the threshold value, that color will be set to black, else set to white (the edge). it results in a black and white image (binary image) but it didnt work that way when i apply it to the RGB channels. :/